# Extract data from Pdf files in R and text mining in R for Image Processing

Tags: r, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, rmagick

I am converting pdf files to text data using Tesseract and pdf_convert to extract the information, but after pdf_convert, I need to darken and resize the data to get the information. I am using the below code:

```
pngfile <- pdftools::pdf_convert('C:/Users/tmpxk9/Desktop/Sunil_TS/Intern/IRD_1/XXXX.pdf', dpi = 600)



input <- magick::image_read("pngfile")

text <- input %>%
  magick::image_resize("2000x") %>%
  magick::image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>%
  magick::image_trim(fuzz = 40) %>%
  magick::image_write(format = 'png', density = '300x300') %>%
  tesseract::ocr() 

cat(text)
```

But image_read is not reading the pngfile that I created, but if I give any individual file with .png it will work.

Note: pdf file has 8 pages, and I need to darken them all to extract information.

Can you please tell me how to proceed here?